# How to test Basic Authentication with Ktor?

Tags: kotlin, testing, ktor

```
fun withTestApp(test: (ApplicationTestBuilder) -> Unit) {
    val testConfig = ApplicationConfig("unit-testing.conf")
    testApplication {
        environment {
            config = testConfig
        }
        application{
            this.module(dependencies = testModule, config = testConfig)
        }
        test(this)
    }
}

fun Application.module(dependencies: Module = koinModule, config: ApplicationConfig = this.environment.config) {
    ConfigAccessor.config = config
    configureSerialization()
    configureHTTP()
    configureSecurity()
    configureRouting()
    install(Koin) {
        slf4jLogger(org.koin.core.logger.Level.ERROR)
        modules(dependencies)
    }
}
```

My routes and security work in the running application. In test cases I can hit unauthenticated routes. The following test fails, however:

```
@Test
fun passesAuth() {
    withTestApp { app ->
        app.startApplication()
        runBlocking {
            val response = app.client.get("/bot") {
                val authString = getAuthString()
                header(HttpHeaders.Authorization, authString)
            }
            assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status)
            assertEquals("Hello Bot!", response.bodyAsText())
        }
    }
```

}
The header is what I would expect and works against the regular application in postman. I'm still getting an Unauthorized response, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HttpMessageBuilder.basicAuth` method to add the `Authorization` header to the request in your test. Here is an example:

```
@Test
fun test() = testApplication {
    application {
        install(Authentication) {
            basic {
                validate {
                    if (it.name == "test" && it.password == "pass") UserIdPrincipal(it.name) else null
                }
            }
        }

        routing {
            authenticate {
                get("/basic") {
                    call.respondText { "GOOD" }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    val response = client.get("/basic") {
        basicAuth("test", "pass")
    }

    assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status)
    assertEquals("GOOD", response.bodyAsText())
}
```